# onclick event not firing in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following `Vue.js` template :

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="ti-page-inquire">
    <div>
        <h3 class="mdc-typography--headline3">{{page.name}}</h3>
        <ti-button v-bind:button="page.button" v-on:click="onSubmit"></ti-button>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="ti-button">
    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" v-bind:title="button.name">{{button.name}}</button>
</script>
```

**script**

```
    Vue.component('ti-page-inquire', { 
        props: ['page'],
        template: '#ti-page-inquire',
        methods : {
            onSubmit : function() {
                alert(1);             
            }
        }
    });

    Vue.component('ti-button', {
        props: ['button'],
        template: '#ti-button',
        mounted: function () {
            // ripple on button
            mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(this.$el);
        }
    });
```

when I click on my custom button, nothing happens. I think it's because its looking for `onSubmit` in the `ti-button` component, but how do I get it to look in the `ti-page-inquire` component?

Comment: Can you show code for `ti-button` component

Comment: I added the button code

Comment: Do you have any component code for the `ti-button` ?

Comment: ok added that too

Comment: @omega what went wrong with my answer?

Comment: @omega check my answer now with code that requires changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components are *black boxes* you should catch all events inside it and emit them to the outer world.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pz6nw183/)

```
Vue.component('ti-button', {
    props: ['button'],
    template: '#ti-button',
    mounted: function () {
        // ripple on button
        mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(this.$el);
    },
    methods: {
      buttonClicked: function() {
        this.$emit('button-clicked');
      }
    }
});


<script type="text/x-template" id="ti-page-inquire">
    <div>
        <h3 class="mdc-typography--headline3">{{page.name}}</h3>
        <ti-button v-bind:button="page.button" v-on:button-clicked="onSubmit"></ti-button>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="ti-button">
    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised" v-bind:title="button.name" @clicked="buttonClicked">{{button.name}}</button>
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, didn't know you need to propagate events up like that.

Comment: Clicking on black box should produce nothing, but when you define events in it, and listen for those events you can hear something. Components are black boxes, they have inputs and outputs, nothing else

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you need to listen for a [native click event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components). So you need to use the `.native` modifier ..

```
<ti-button v-bind:button="page.button" v-on:click.native="onSubmit"></ti-button>
```

This will only work if the button is the root element of your `ti-button` component. Otherwise you'll have to pass your event listeners to your button in the `ti-button` component like this ..

```
<button v-on="$listeners" ...> ... </button>
```

Comment: Well I guess it's the way Vue works according to the docs[1](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)/[2](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

Answer (score 0):

Try to emit an event from `ti-button` component to the parent one by using `this.$emit` function :

```
Vue.component('ti-button', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: '#vButton',

  data: {
    name: 'hi'
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$emit('submit')
    }
  }
});
```

```
<template id="vButton">
    <button v-bind:title="name" @click="submit">{{name}}</button>
</template>
```

the emitted event `submit` it called in the parent component like `v-on:submit="onSubmit"` and handled using `onSubmit` method:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="ti-page-inquire">
  <div>
    <h3 class="mdc-typography--headline3">{{page.name}}</h3>
    <ti-button v-bind:button="page.button" v-on:submit="onSubmit"></ti-button>
  </div>
</script>

  Vue.component('ti-page-inquire', { 
       props: ['page'],
       template: '#ti-page-inquire',
        methods : {
        onSubmit : function() {
            alert(1);             
         }
        }
    });
```

Sometimes you need also to emit some parameters, so you could do it like :

```
    this.$emit('submit',params)
```

`params` could be of any type